# Is it possible to GET or PUT two specific files at a time using SFTP without wildcard?

Tags: sftp, files, wildcard

From a directory of dozens of files, **is it possible to GET or PUT two files at once using SFTP**?

**I do not want to use a wildcard** because I don't necessarily know the names of all the files and don't want to affect other files.

I'm hoping there's something like:

```
get javascript.gs,stylesheet.css
```

From Google searching and looking on various Stackexchanges, it doesn't look like this is possible.

**Does anyone know for sure?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do:

```
sftp user@host << EOF!
get /path/to/file1
get /path/to/file2
EOF!
```

But personally I prefer to use `scp` in such cases.

Answer (score 5):

If possible, use `lftp` as your sftp client (available for all the relevant Linux distros and *BSDs in their package collections):

```
lftp sftp://someaccount@somehost.com
```

Then you can use `mget`command:

```
mget javascript.gs stylesheet.css
```

If `lftp` is not possible to use, then you can use `-b` (batch) option in standard `sftp` command. First create a text file containing

```
get javascript.gs
get stylesheet.css
```

And then use command

```
sftp -b yourtextfile.txt someaccount@somehost.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with sftp, the syntax for get is get remote-path [local-path] which means that the second parameter if supplied will be used to rename the file on the local system. Similarly put would rename the uploaded file if a second parameter is supplied.

You could use scp to to the job

```
scp user@remote.tld:"/path/to/javascript.gs /path/to/stylesheet.css" /local/path
```

You could also use an sftp script.